# Склоняется ли мужская фамилия Эбель?

Tags: склонение

Склоняется ли мужская фамилия Эбель?

Answer (score 1):

Да. Как и "Монтень", например.

С "Грамоты":

> Все прочие мужские фамилии, имеющие основы на согласные и нулевое
>   окончание в именительном падеже (на письме они кончаются согласной
>   буквой, ь или й), кроме фамилий на -ых, -их, склоняются как
>   существительные второго склонения мужского рода, т. е. имеют в
>   творительном падеже окончание -ом, (-ем): *Герценом, Левитаном,
>   Гоголем, Врубелем, Хемингуэем, Гайдаем*. Такие фамилии воспринимаются
>   как «нерусские».
>
> Соотносительные женские фамилии не склоняются: Наталии Александровны
>   Герцен, Любови Дмитриевне Блок, с Анной Магдалиной Бах, с Надеждой
>   Ивановной Забелой-Врубель, о Мэри Хемингуэй, о Зое Гайдай.
>
> Примечание. Применение этого правила требует знания пола носителя
>   фамилии. Отсутствие таких сведений ставит пишущего в затруднительное
>   положение.

Тоже с "Грамоты":

> 4. Если фамилия оканчивается на согласный (кроме фамилий на -ых, -их, о которых говорилось выше), то здесь – и только здесь! – имеет
>      значение пол носителя фамилии. Все мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на
>      согласный, склоняются – это закон русской грамматики. Все женские
>      фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, не склоняются. При этом языковое
>      происхождение фамилии не имеет значения. Склоняются в том числе и
>      мужские фамилии, совпадающие с нарицательными существительными.
>      Примеры: тетрадь Михаила Бока, дипломы выданы Александру Кругу и
>      *Константину Королю*, встреча с Игорем Шипелевичем, в гостях у Андрея
>      Мартынюка, дочь Ильи Скалозуба, работа Исаака Акопяна; тетрадь Анны
>      Бок, дипломы выданы Наталье Круг и Лидии Король, встреча с Юлией
>      Шипелевич, в гостях у Екатерины Мартынюк, дочь Светланы Скалозуб,
>      работа Марины Акопян.

Answer (score 1):

*Альфред Нобель* — фамилию точно склоняют. Соответственно, *Эбель* тоже склоняется.

Comment: Аналогии не всегда действуют, наппример, фамилия у француского философа Жака Деррида не склоняется, а у Григория Сковороды - склоняется.

Comment: Здесь аж 4 буквы совпадают.